# Google Sheets, Invalid Formula: Need fix for Conditional Formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

When I paste `=and(V26<0,Settings!C14=TRUE)` in a cell, it evaluates correctly, to `TRUE`.

When I enter the same formula in `Custom Formula` I get an error as shown.

How can I correct this please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `Indirect` is a way to go

`=and(V26<0,INDIRECT("Settings!C14")=TRUE)`

works